# VS.NET: Doing a post-build step in a web project

Tags: javascript, .net, build-process, minify

I've got a Visual Studio 2010 solution with only a website in it. It contains lots of Javascript files which I would like to minimize automatically when doing a build. There's one good [solution](http://encosia.com/2009/05/20/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/) but it dpeends on the post-build step of .NET projects and a website does not have any build events.

One alternative is of course to run something on the commandline manually whenever doing a build. Is there any other way to integrate it into VS build process except the post-build step?

Comment: Is it a Asp.Net web application? When you say minimize do you mean compress?

Comment: Compression is done via IIS. I'd like to minimize the .js with jsmin before doing the compression.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, its not possible, its just not a feature for websites, which are ment to be almost an xcopy deployment. if someone does know a way then please let us all know.

its a good idea to have a 1-click batch/powershell deployment script for these sort of projects, and well, all projects really. you can add the script to your VS IDE either via a macro, or *Tools->External Tools...* the inbuilt publish mechanism is fairly limited, doesn't even support SCP, so the script solution ends up as the work around again.

if you can, convert it to a web application, its a much better experience imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform post build events on web projects if you install the [VS 2010 Web Deployment Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx) extension/power tool.

For how to add in to your solution, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/14/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-beta-avail-now.aspx).

You can uncomment the `<Target Name="AfterBuild">` tag (as an example) inside the .wdproj file.